# decltype::static_member C++

Tags: c++, templates, reflection, decltype

As the title suggests, I was trying to use decltype to get the type of a template. The way i tried this was:

```
template<typename T> class List
{
....
public:
    typedef T type;
....
};
```

MAIN.CPP

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    List<int> intl;
    decltype(intl)::type t;  // compiler doesnt try to access the decltype's members but reverts to global namespace (as if i had typed :: on a new line
}
```

It was my impression that decltype returned a type as if you had written it litterally (aka "int" in code). Is this not the case?

Also, is there any other way to get typename T from a template class?

Thanks in advance.

EXTENTION:

```
    List<int> intl;
typedef decltype(intl) listtype;
listtype::type i;
```

i is an unsigned int... im confuzled

Ok found it. WOO 2 compiler errors in 1 :) i had a for loop declaring unsigned int (which then went out of scope but for some reason it as still an unsigned int when i used it later

Comment: I've seen this before, it's a bug in your compiler.

Comment: ^^ yep, it should work. You might be able to workaround the bug with `typedef decltype(intl) list_type; list_type::type t;`.  When asking "is this valid?" **always** say what compiler you're using! Until all compilers support C++11 100% it's **very** relevant to say which compiler gives you an error

Comment: @SethCarnegie so its meant to work? that is very good news indeed. Im using VC++ 2010 so it will prob work as expected in 2012... i hope

Comment: @SethCarnegie yep thats EXACTLY what i get. ty muchly

Comment: @MrUniverse: It's broken in MSVC2012 as well, just tested. Here it is working on gcc: http://ideone.com/h63Bs5. The workaround Jonathan gives does fix the problem.

Comment: @GManNickG the typedef workaround works. it is dependency free and cleaner so im using it. But still getting some weird results (as stated in EXTENTION:)

Comment: @MrUniverse - To VC2010's defense - this wasn't originally allowed, and was added rather late in the standard process. For VC2012, there is no defense...